# Tips on passing "this" reference to a method in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, reference, this

So for my code below, I'm trying to pass the "this" keyword of the outer function into the draw_bldText(...) function. But how do can i do this? When I call this inside the execute, "this" refers inside the function scope. I want the "this" keyword from this.piece.

I hope my question makes sense, I'm new to javascript

```
this.myDrawFunction;
this.piece = this;
switch(image) {
    case "blank":
        break;
    case "bldText":
    myDrawFunction = {
        execute : function() {
            draw_bldText(this, this_popup.context, this_popup.focus);       
        }
        };
    . . .
    . . .
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you show how you call `myDrawFunction.execute()`. (Also, your first line, `this.myDrawFunction;`, doesn't do anything.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind a local variable to `this`, and use that so that it will be saved in the closure:

```
some_func() {
    var that = this;
    myDrawFunction = {
        execute: function() {
            draw_bldText(that, this_popup.context, this_popup.focus);
        }
    };
}
```